# Testcafe TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined

Tags: testing, logging, automated-tests, typeerror, testcafe

Rather new to Testcafe, i have constructed a logger and loggerResponseBody function. But when running the tests, it gives me typeerrors. Also the tests used to work some time ago.
Code of logger and loggerResponseBody: (the logger and loggerResponseBody are in different files)

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe'

import { BASE_URL } from '../consts/generic'

export const logger = (endpoint, method = 'GET') =>
  RequestLogger(
    { url: `${BASE_URL}/api/v1/${endpoint}/`, method },
    {
      logResponseHeaders: true,
      logResponseBody: true
    }
  )

export const loggerResponseBody = (logger, requestNumber = 0) =>
  JSON.parse(logger.requests[requestNumber].response.body.toString())
```

Which gives the error:

```
   1) TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined

      Browser: Chrome 85.0.4183 / Linux 0.0.0

         10 |      logResponseBody: true
         11 |    }
         12 |  )
         13 |
         14 |export const loggerResponseBody = (logger, requestNumber = 0) =>
       > 15 |  JSON.parse(logger.requests[requestNumber].response.body.toString())
         16 |
```

Comment: not familiar with testcafe, but if I understand the code correctly: why does the default value of requestNumber change from requestnumber = 0 in the sourcefile  to requestnumber = 1 during the typeerror traceback?

Comment: lol, its the output from when i tried to change some values, will adjust the value in the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you log the request before the server responds. You can wait for the response by executing

`await t.expect(logger.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();`

`RequestLogger.contains` and `RequestLogger.count` use the [Smart Assertion Query Mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html#smart-assertion-query-mechanism) which ensures that the response is received.

For more information on logging HTTP requests, see [Intercept HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html).

If this doesn't resolve the issue, please attach your test code so that we could identify its cause.